# ¿Cómo relaciono un vendedor y un comprador (ambos almacenados en la tabla users) con una orden de compra?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

Estoy desarrollando una plataforma de compra/venta en CakePHP con MySQL. Cada usuario que se registra es tanto comprador como vendedor, aunque alguno de los roles puede no ser ejercido por determinados usuarios; es decir, un usuario puede estar interesado únicamente en vender y otro sólo en comprar. En base a esto:

- He creado una tabla llamada "users" para almacenar a los usuarios que, como antes dije, son compradores y vendedores al mismo tiempo.
- He creado otra tabla llamada "orders" en la cual se almacenan las ordenes que realiza un comprador a un vendedor. Cada registro de esta tabla, es decir, cada orden (o pedido), debe almacenar dos IDs de la tabla "users", uno para el comprador y otro para el vendedor.

De acuerdo a lo anterior, mi duda es la siguiente: ¿debo definir una relación de **muchos a muchos**, entre ambas tablas, para establecer que **muchas ordenes pueden tener muchos usuarios** (técnicamente, sólo dos: un comprador y un vendedor) y **muchos usuarios pueden tener muchas ordenes**?

Comment: Podría funcionar tal y como lo tienes: una tabla `users` con las columnas `user_id, user ... etc`  y una tabla `orders` con las columnas `order_id (llave primaria), comprador_id, vendedor_id, fecha... etc` en ese caso la tabla orders no tendría más índice que la clave primaria, ya que en la misma fecha podría ocurrir más de una orden entre un comprador y un vendedor. Ahora bien, hay que analizar el problema en su conjunto, por ejemplo, cómo estarían diseñadas las tablas `productos, facturas, etc`.

Comment: Sería bueno que analices algunos esquemas posibles como: [este](http://old.vk.pp.ru/docs/sybase-any/remote/gif/asademo.gif), o [este](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/MySQL-Sample-Database-Schema.png) o bien [este](http://www.netthruoffice.com/doc/images/customer-delivery.gif). Conviene que hagas un diseño de conjunto, tomando en cuenta las otras tablas que intervienen en la base de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En mi opinion, tu tabla "orders" debe diferenciar los dos ids que se estan almacenando en ella, es decir se debe saber que id es el comprador, y que id es el vendedor, en este orden de ideas la relacion es de uno a muchos ya que una orden tiene un solo vendedor y un solo comprador, y un vendedor o comprador puede tener muchas ordenes, para ello aconsejaria crear una tabla "vendedores" y una tabla "compradores" donde se relacionen el id del usuario con el id que tendra como comprador o vendedor segun sea la tabla, y de estas tablas sacar los ids para relacionarlos en la tabla orders, esa es la posible solución que yo veo, pero hay varias formas de hacerlo

Comment: Entiendo. Pero lo que sucede con tu planteo, según entiendo, es que el mismo deriva en dos tablas (compradores y vendedores) que tienen la misma información, ya que un usuario que está en una tabla, también debe estar en la otra porque puede ser tanto comprador como vendedor. Esta resolución implica información duplicada y, en lo que concierne a la base de datos, no lo veo muy eficiente.

Comment: Estás en lo cierto al decir que si hay información duplicada la base de datos no estaria bien formada de acuerdo a las formas de normalización de base de datos, aún asi mi planteamiento no duplica información, ya he formado dos proyectos que tienen una situación similar, y te explico porque no se duplican datos.

Comment: La tabla usuario contiene todos los datos del usuarios como su informacion personal, nombre de usuario, contraseña y demás. La tabla compradores tiene la información del usuario como comprador, reputación como comprador, ventas efectuadas y demás, y la tabla vendedor igual, pero con la información del vendedor. Tambien hay que tener en cuenta que comprador, vendedor, y usuario son entidades diferentes por mas de que sea una misma persona, que debiste notarlo en tu modelo entidad relación.

Comment: En conclusión, separas las entidades y manejas la información de cada entidad por aparte, relacionandola por el id del usuario, y de esta forma no hay campos repetidos

Comment: Las respuestas mas acertadas serán las que te digan que separes las entidades, como yo lo plantee

Comment: Ahora sí terminé de entender. Excelente. Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Tu idea sería básicamente:

```
Users: [id]
Orders: [id_comprador], [id_vendedor]
```

Y obviamente lo que tendrías es una doble relación entre `Orders` y `Users`. Si bien es factible como modelo, tiene la limitación en que debes compartir los datos propios de un comprador y los datos propios de un vendedor en una sola entidad `Users`, cuando un `user` es solamente vendedor o solamente comprador se ve bien el problema. Si la mayor parte de los casos los usuarios son compradores y vendedores puede ser un modelo  posible. Sino hay que plantearse algo distinto como lo siguiente:

```
Users: [id]
UsersCompradores: [id], [id_user]
UsersVendedores: [id], [id_user]
Orders: [id_usercomprador], [id_uservendedor]
```

Con este modelo, tienes dos tablas para definir cuales usuarios son vendedores y cuales compradores (estarán en ambas tablas si tienen los dos roles), y `Orders` tendría una relación 1 a 1 a `UsersVendedores` y otra 1 a 1 a `UsersCompradores`, por otro lado estas dos tablas también tendrían una relación 1 a 1 con `Users`, esto es lo que se conoce como relaciones ternarias. La complejidad, que tampoco es mucha, es que necesitarías agregar siempre un `JOIN` a una tabla más para tener los datos del usuario como usuario y del usuario como comprador/vendedor